# Why does jquery post json as a parameter name instead of as the request body?

Tags: jquery, json, rest, scalatra

For a webapp with a RESTful backend I am posting some json to the server using jquery's [$post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/). Now to my surprise, the json is stuffed in a parameter key for the request's form data, instead of in the request body. I can think of some [other ways to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4159701/jquery-posting-valid-json-in-request-body), but the question is why it doesn't work as I expect.

On the server I use scalatra and print some request info:

```
println("Request received:")
println(fromInputStream(request.getInputStream).getLines().mkString)
println("--------------")
println(request.getParameterMap.toString)
println("==============")
```

Now a simple curl that does what I think is right:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/x -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"a":"b"}'
```

Produces:

```
Request received:
{"a":"b"}
-------------
{}
==============
```

And the bit of html+js to illustrate the problem:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<body>
  <button type="button" onclick="doPost()">
    POST
  </button>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
function doPost() {
    $.post("http://localhost:8080/x",     
           JSON.stringify({"a":"b"} ), 
           function(data) {});
}
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Produces:

```
Request received:

--------------
{{"a":"b"}=[Ljava.lang.String;@7a2897ac}
==============
```

So if I use $post with a stringified json string and a callback I get everything stuffed in a single parameter key. If this is normal, I would like to know why, and how I'm supposed to unravel this cleanly on the server. If it is not normal, I'd like to know what I should do to to get it in the response body using $post.

UPDATE: There is now a [feature request for jquery to support contentType on $.post](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11134)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you can do this if you drop down to [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

```
$.ajax(
  {
     url: "http://localhost:8080/x",
     data: JSON.stringify({a: 'b'}),
     processData: false,
     type: 'POST',
     contentType: 'application/json'
  }
);
```

`processData` tells jquery not to mess around with your data and setting `contentType` should ensure that your backend doesn't try and parse the json as it were a regular url encoded form.

Answer (score 4):

You are not setting the content-type which is causing the $.post() method to set it to application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

Use $.ajax() and set the content-type to application/json explicitly.

Regards, Vincent.

Answer (score 0):

Vincent Partington is right, the default contentType is set to application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Use the jQuery.ajax function directly instead or create your own shorthand.

You can also change the server side, see
[Spring 3 MVC - Advanced Data Binding - Form Request with List of Simple Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3566201/spring-3-mvc-advanced-data-binding-form-request-with-list-of-simple-objects)
for example. But I would just use the full ajax function.