# Spring JSON+RestFul

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc

I have a project that has ability of Core Spring and I want to add RestFul Ability,
Actually I want to send and Receive JSON data through Spring Web MVC or Whatelse others.
Imagine that,
I have a Hibernate Entity names is category.
I want to send this Entity as Json Data with Spring and 
I want to send List as Json Data,also .Naturally, I want to take this Json data 
from someWhere with Spring .

How can I do this Ability with spring ?
Are there any tutorials?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to have `jackson` in your Classpath for Spring to render the response as json.

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html#view-json-mapping

[Spring 3.0 making JSON response using jackson message converter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259551/spring-3-0-making-json-response-using-jackson-message-converter)

Comment: Again hello guys, I did your suggestion but I have a new problem with Json,When I tyr to send List<Category> with ResponseBody Annotation,it download as a file without extension and I am downloading it open it so I can see my data as Json Format, Is this normal to download a file?

Comment: @CetinImre if you use Firefox it opens is as a downloadable file however Chromium doesn't. Plugin is here: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/jsonview/

Answer (score 1):

In addition you also need to make sure that you have the following line in your Spring XML:

```
<context:annotation-config />
```

Otherwise jackson will not be enabled.

As the result, all methods which are mapped by `@ResponseBody` and returns object will be serialized and returned as response using `application/json` content type.

Comment: My Json data looks like [{"name":"cat","id":1,"category":null,"categories":null}{"name":"cat","id":1,"category":null,"categories":null},{"name":"cat","id":1,"category":null,"categories":null},{"name":"cat","id":1,"category":null,"categories":null},{"name":"cat","id":1,"category":null,"categories":null}]

but ı dont see information beginning of json data like this ‎{"status":"OK","msg":"","count":"37","results":

how can I this?