# EXTJS and Spring MVC Portlet File Upload

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, file-upload, extjs, portlet

I have successfully been able to upload a file to my ActionResponse method in my controller for my spring portlet using extjs.  My problem is that extjs is expecting a json response in order to know the upload is complete, and the response for my action request renders out the entire portal.

I am needing a way to tell the response for my request to only be a json string.

here is my controller.

```
@Controller
```

@RequestMapping(value = "VIEW") 
public class MediaRoomViewController {

```
private static final Logger _log = Logger.getLogger(MediaRoomViewController.class);

@RenderMapping
public String renderView(RenderRequest request, RenderResponse response, Model model){
    return "view";
}

@InitBinder
protected void initBinder(PortletRequest request, PortletRequestDataBinder binder) throws Exception {
    // to actually be able to convert Multipart instance to byte[]
    // we have to register a custom editor
    binder.registerCustomEditor(byte[].class, new ByteArrayMultipartFileEditor());
    // now Spring knows how to handle multipart object and convert
}

@ActionMapping(params="action=uploadFile")
public String uploadFile(FileUploadBean uploadItem, BindingResult result,ActionResponse response) throws Exception {
    _log.debug("Upload File Action");

    ExtJSFormResult extjsFormResult = new ExtJSFormResult();
    try{
        if (result.hasErrors()){
            for(ObjectError error : result.getAllErrors()){
                System.err.println("Error: " + error.getCode() +  " - " + error.getDefaultMessage());
            }

            //set extjs return - error
            extjsFormResult.setSuccess(false);
        }

        // Some type of file processing...
        System.err.println("-------------------------------------------");
        System.err.println("Test upload: " + uploadItem.getFile().getOriginalFilename());
        System.err.println("-------------------------------------------");

        //set extjs return - sucsess
        extjsFormResult.setSuccess(true);
    }catch(Exception ex){
        _log.error(ex,ex);
    }
    return extjsFormResult.toString();
}
```

here is my extjs file upload code

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
            title: 'File Uploader',
            width: 400,
            bodyPadding: 10,
            frame: true,
            renderTo: self._Namespace + 'file-upload',    
            items: [{
                xtype: 'filefield',
                name: 'file',
                fieldLabel: 'File',
                labelWidth: 50,
                msgTarget: 'side',
                allowBlank: false,
                anchor: '100%',
                buttonText: 'Select a File...'
            }],

            buttons: [{
                text: 'Upload',
                handler: function() {
                    var form = this.up('form').getForm();
                    if(form.isValid()){
                        form.submit({
                            url: self._Urls[0],
                            waitMsg: 'Uploading your file...',
                            success: function(form,action) {
                               alert("success");
                            },
                            failure: function(form,action){
                                alert("error");
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }]
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to go here:

---

1. Manually force response as text like this

   response.setContentType("text/html"); //or json if u wish

   responseText = "{'success':'true'}";

   response.getWriter().write(responseText);
2. Use Jackson lib as covered here:
   [Spring 3.0 making JSON response using jackson message converter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259551/spring-3-0-making-json-response-using-jackson-message-converter)
3. Move on to Grails and forget about verbose MVC configs.  **My preferred method :)**

Comment: 1. there is not way to set content type on an action response,  ActionResponse does not have anyway of even writting to the response.  2. Converting my results to json is not the issue, I need my results to not render out the entire portal wrapper. 3. This is not a decision to be made by me, spring mvc is a corporate standard.

Comment: Didn't realize you are using a Portal!