# How to get String array from controller using @ResponseBody?

Tags: java, spring, jquery, spring-mvc

I'm using @ResponseBody to get the json to Browser.I could get the data,but now if I try getting array of Strings or list of Strings then I get the following

> The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating
>   responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request
>   "accept" headers ().

Why the above status?

The following is the Object I'm returning from controller

```
public  class Temp
{    
 List<String> strArr=new ArrayList<String>();   
 public Temp()
 {
    strArr.add("1");
    strArr.add("2");
    strArr.add("3");
    strArr.add("4");
    System.out.println("temp="+strArr);
 }
}
```

The following is the controller

```
@RequestMapping ( value = "/temp.htm" , method = RequestMethod.GET,produces="application/json")
public @ResponseBody Temp getTemp()
{
        return new Temp();
}
```

I could get normal String data but if I try to get array or list of String I get the above status.

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) You need to set your accept headers to `application/json`

b) Your bean class is not a proper Java bean. You need to expose a getter method:

```
public List<String> getStrArr(){return strAddr;}
```

c) Do you have Jackson on your classpath, and do you have a proper mvc config? In most cases, this will be enough:

```
 <mvc:annotation-driven />
```

(see [this section](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-enable))

d) I'm guessing you have to remove the `@ResponseBody` annotation. It's for direct output of a string, not for implicit conversion of an object.

Comment: yes this worked,sorry I missed very basic part.Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up a converter to convert the response to json, such as:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
   <property name="messageConverters">
      <list>
         <ref bean="jacksonJsonMessageConverter"/>
      </list>
   </property>
</bean>
```

This will use [Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes) to convert the response to json.  You'll need to add the Jackson lib as a dependency, more details can be found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259551/spring-3-0-making-json-response-using-jackson-message-converter).  Jackson will convert any public fields, so you would need to add a `getStrArr()` method to `Temp` for `strArr`.

Comment: I'm using <mvc:annotation-driven /> which is internally taking care of httpMessageConversions.