# How to accept JavaScript Array parameter in Spring MVC Controller in a jQuery ajax call?

Tags: java, spring, jquery, spring-mvc

I hava a jQuery ajax call like this:

```
var arr = ["a", "b", "c"];
$.get("/test", {testArray: arr}, function(data) {
    alert(data);
});
```

server side:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String addAnotherAppointment(
        HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response,
                    @RequestParam("arr") arr,
        Model model,
        BindingResult errors) {
}
```

So how do I receive the parameter?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use spring 3.0++,use "@ResponseBody" annotation.

Do you want to send a json request, and receive a response from json?
If so, you'll change your code like this.

```
var list = {testArray:["a", "b", "c"]};
$.ajax({
    url : '/test',
    data : $.toJSON(list),
    type : 'POST', //<== not 'GET',
    contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType : 'json',
    error : function() {
        console.log("error");
    },
    success : function(arr) {
        console.log(arr.testArray);
        var testArray = arr.testArray;
         $.each(function(i,e) {
             document.writeln(e);
         });
    }
  });
```

server side:

1. create your own "Arr" class.

   ```
   public class Arr {
    private List<String> testArray;
    public void setTestArray(List<String> testArray) {
        this.testArray = testArray;
    }
    public List<String> getTestArray() {
        return testArray;
    }
    }
   ```

   and

   ```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
   @ResponseBody// <== this annotation will bind Arr class and convert to json response.
      public Arr addAnotherAppointment(
      HttpServletRequest request,
       HttpServletResponse response,
       @RequestBody Arr arr, 
       Model model,
       BindingResult errors) {
           return arr;
   }
   ```

Comment: read this Q&A: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259551/spring-3-0-making-json-response-using-jackson-message-converter

Comment: Basically, you need a wrapper class to contain your array in your controller.

Answer (score 1):

Change `@RequestParam("arr") arr,` to `@RequestParam("testArray") String[] arr`

Also change your HTTP method from `get` to `post`

Please note @RequestParam value must match the parameter name send from the jquery ajax . In your case the param name is `testArray` and value is `arr`